# SSO Integration using Okta

Tags: single-sign-on, okta

Wanted to use Okta to log in to our application, so we did it using SSO integration. If using Godaddy Cloud, it works great, however if using Google Cloud, we see a white label error page. The Google Cloud is where we actually want to access it. Please provide advice on what to do in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the limited details provided, I presume that Okta is being used for SAML SSO to G-Cloud. If that is the case, then review this reference link: https://saml-doc.okta.com/SAML_Docs/How-to-Configure-SAML-2.0-for-Google-Cloud-Platform.html

Usually, the most common reason for a blank page post-authentication is SAML response is not fully consumed by the SP(GCloud in this case).